# error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]|

Tags: c++, char, integer

this is a code to validate a password. the input string is being checked for digits, special characters, length of string and lower and upper case characters.
that particular block of for loop where string elements are being compared to special character, gives this error. I tried initializing those special characters to char variables for comparison but error persist.

```
char k='@';
char n='#';
char m='$';
for(i=0; i<l; i++)
        {
            if(password[i]==k || password[i]==n || password==m)     
            {
                counts++;
            }
        }
```

I tried comparing them as this, but same error

```
 if(password[i]=='@' || password[i]=='#' || password=='$')     
            {
                counts++;
            }
```

this is the code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<string.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
     char password[20];
     char k='@';
     char n='#';
     char m='$';
     int i,j,l,countd=0,counts=0,countl=0,countu=0;
     cout<<"enter a password with following conditions :\n1. There should be atleast one digit. \n2. 
 there should be atleast one of #, @, $";
    cout<<"3. password should be between 6 to 20 characters \n4.there should be more uppercase 
letters than lower case\n";
cout<<"5. Should start with uppercase and end with lowercase";

do
{
    countd=0,counts=0,countl=0,countu=0;
    cout<<endl<<"ENTER PASSWORD :";
    cin.getline(password,20);
    l=strlen(password);
    if(l>20 || l<6)
    {
        cout<<"password length should be between 6 to 20 characters \n";
    }
    if(islower(password[0]))
    {
        cout<<" first letter should be uppercase \n";
    }
    if(isupper(password[l-1]))
    {
        cout<<" last letter should be lowercase \n";
    }


    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        for(j='0'; j<='9'; j++)
        {
            if(password[i]==j)
            {
                countd++;

            }

        }
    }
    if(countd<1)
    {
        cout<<" password should contain atleast one digit \n";
    }

    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(password[i]==k || password[i]==n || password==m)     //char k='@'; char n='#'; char m='$'; |56|error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]|
        {
            counts++;
        }
    }


    if(counts<1)
    {
        cout<<"password should contain atleast one of the three special character \n";
    }


    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        for(j='A'; j<='Z'; j++)
        {
            if(password[i]==j)
            {
                countu++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        for(j='a'; j<='z'; j++)
        {
            if(password[i]==j)
            {
                countl++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(countu<countl)
    {
        cout<<"number of uppercase letters should be more than lowercase \n";
    }

}

while((countu<countl) || (counts<1) (isupper(password[l-1])) || (islower(password[0])) || l>20 || l<6 || (countd<1));

cout<<endl<<"password accepted/validated "<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

minimal reproducible example.
just want a way to compare the input string with special character.

```
char password[20];
char k='@';
char n='#';
char m='$';
for(i=0; i<l; i++)
        {
            if(password[i]==k || password[i]==n || password==m)   
            {
                counts++;
            }
        }
```

How can i make that comparison happen?
Please do guide.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: If you are lucky your compiler should also give you a column pointer, which will tell you which of the three index brackets you forgot!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: Why would would expect to be able to meaningfully compare a pointer and an integer ??

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies. the problem was of indices bracket and `(counts<1) (isupper(password[l-1])) ` which is now corrected to `(counts<1) ||(isupper(password[l-1])) ` program is working now. thanks again !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
if(password[i]==k || password[i]==n || password==m)
```

should read

```
if(password[i]==k || password[i]==n || password[i]==m)
```

Note the missing brackets on the last term.